# PHP Require file inside Static Method

Tags: php, class, methods, include, require

In my class I've got a Method, that includes diffrent Files based on the input.

The Files are included correctly => var_dump shows "true".

BUT!! If I want to access the included variable, it tells me, that it's not defined....

The included file:

```
<?php
$cpucooler = array(
array(
    "Name" => "Boxed CPU Lüfter",
    "Sockel" => "Alle",
    "Leistung" => 20,
    "RPM" => 2000,
    "Preis" => 0
));
?>
```

The Class Method:

```
/**
 * Get Hardware for classes
 * @param string $type Hardware type
 * @return array
 */
public static function getHardware($type) {
    switch ($type) {
        case 'cpucooler':
            require_once "hardware/cpucooler.php";
            var_dump($cpucooler); // undefined variable...
            return $cpucooler;
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me

Comment: I only get that error when I cannot include the file. If that works, I also get the data. Tested with WampServer.

Comment: Make sure that your file is really being included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File was correctly included, the Problem was, that I used

```
require_once $file;
return $cpucooler;
```

instead of

```
require $file;
return $cpucooler;
```

Don't know why...

Comment: Very very strange behavior !

Answer (score 0):

I get that error when I cannot include the file. 
If including works, I also get the data.

In conclusion, since failing to open the file is not a fatal error (just a warning), you probably have disabled outputting warnings, so you don't see them. If you [enable error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), you should see the warning.

The exact cause of failure is a guess. Maybe the path is incorrect, because you made a typo, or the case of the name is wrong, or the current directory is different from what you think. (try using an absolute path and/or check using the `__DIR__` constant.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `hardware/cpucooler.php` is really being included. It's a good practice to use [is_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) to make sure that you `require` file that exists in your application.

```
try {
    $filepath = 'hardware/cpucooler.php';
    if( ! is_file(  $filepath ) ) {
        throw new Exception( $filepath . ' do not exists.' );
    } 
    // If exception is thrown, the following code is not executed.
    require $filepath;
    return $cpucooler;
} catch( Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```